# Spring Netflix Feign - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-feign

Very new to spring cloud.

Implementing Spring Cloud Feign and running into issues. Eureka server is up and running and the below services are registering in that.

GreetingApp

```
application.properties
server.port= 14000
server.context-path= /greetservices


spring.application.name=GreetingApp
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class GreetingappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class GreetingController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public String greetUser() {
        logger.debug(" **** In greetUser(): Server Port " + environment.getProperty("local.server.port"));
        return "Hello " + "Abdul";
    }
}
```

I am able to access this app normally.

**Feign Client App**

application.properties

```
server.port= 15000

server.context-path= /gaconsumerservice

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

spring.application.name=GreetingAppFeignConsumer

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureak.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureak.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

**Main Class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableEurekaClient
public class GreetingappconsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingappconsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

**Feign client Interface**

```
@FeignClient(name = "GreetingApp")
public interface GAConsumerService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetUser();
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public class GAConsumerController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    GAConsumerService gaConsumerService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/user")
    public String greetUser() {
        logger.debug(" *** In /feign/gaconsumer::greetUser()");
        return gaConsumerService.greetUser();
    }

}
```

After all this when I try to access the below url its throwing below exception

**Success:** http://localhost:14000/greetservices/greeting/user

**Exception:** http://localhost:15000/gaconsumerservice/greeting/user

```
2019-07-24 16:25:42,109 INFO  [http-nio-15000-exec-3]
                com.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty$ChainLink: Flipping property: GreetingApp.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2019-07-24 16:25:42,117 INFO  [http-nio-15000-exec-3]
                com.netflix.loadbalancer.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client GreetingApp initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=GreetingApp,current list of Servers=[localhost:14000],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;  Instance count:1;   Active connections count: 0;    Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;   Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:localhost:14000;   Zone:defaultZone;   Total Requests:0;   Successive connection failure:0;    Total blackout seconds:0;   Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;  First connection made: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970;    Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0; average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;    min resp time:0.0;  max resp time:0.0;  stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@363b7066
2019-07-24 16:25:42,569 ERROR [http-nio-15000-exec-3]
                org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/gaconsumerservice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: status 404 reading GAConsumerService#greetUser(); content:
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1></body></html>] with root cause
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading GAConsumerService#greetUser(); content:
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1></body></html>
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.greetUser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hams.services.greetingappconsumer.controller.GAConsumerController.greetUser(GAConsumerController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please help.

Comment: @FeignClient(name = "GreetingApp")
public interface GAConsumerService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greetservices/greeting/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetUser();
}

Answer (score 0):

Please add @ResponseBody to Feign client Interface

```
public interface GAConsumerService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody public String greetUser();
}
```